# How to format ZoneDateTime in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, java-8, timestamp, format

I want to format current date in some format.

Format : 20200807|12:44:55.000

But by using following code is prints only till seconds. I want to prints till miliseconds.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd|HH:mm:ss");
String formattedString1 = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter1);
System.out.println(formattedString1);
```

Comment: You should tell the pattern to consider milliseconds, too... What exactly do you need? Milliseconds of day or fraction of second?

Comment: Where is your attempt? Your pattern obviously does not include milliseconds. Why don't you try to do that?

Comment: @f1sh I am pretty sure OP thinks this code can be considered an attempt while coders who know `java.time` cannot. Hard to tell if the question contains an actual attempt or not...

Comment: @deHaar imho it's *very* obvious to OP that the pattern needs to be extended, since that's all the snippet is about. But instead of reading the pattern's documentation and figuring it out, OP posts this question. That's why I don't consider this an attempt. And the number of downvotes say the same thing.

Comment: @f1sh Yes, I finally agree... Maybe I was too lenient here.

Comment: @deHaar it's fine, you're just trying to do the right thing. I just expect more of members with almost 2k reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically extend the pattern `String` you are using, it currently (and obviously) only formats time units down to seconds (`HH:mm:ss` ⇒ hours, minutes & seconds).

Make it `"yyyyMMdd|HH:mm:ss.SSS"` in order to have fraction of second,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd|HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String formattedString1 = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter1);
    System.out.println(formattedString1);
}
```

this would output a `String` of the form the following one has:

```
20200807|10:57:17.547
```

If you need milliseconds of day (whysoever), you can use a single `A` instead of those three `S`.

Have a look at the [JavaDocs of `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for pattern letters and their meanings.

Here's a small excerpt:

```
   ...
   H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
   m       minute-of-hour              number            30
   s       second-of-minute            number            55
   S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
   A       milli-of-day                number            1234
   n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
   N       nano-of-day                 number            1234000000
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the pattern to include milliseconds.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd|HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedString1 = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter1);
System.out.println(formattedString1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not considering milliseconds in pattern. So you need to update your pattern as below :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd|HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

For more details you can refer [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).